# How to migrate a dataplex glossary to another project in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a project in google cloud and later i created a glossary in dataplex i have to migrate this glossary to another project.

I expected to the dataplex glossary will be located in another new project that i created

Comment: Sadly not... Datacatalog entry are global but business glossary is attached to a project. You have to get all your entries and load them in the target project. So boring, I admit.